# Can I filter by a property and scope variable in angular?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Let's say that

```
$scope.xs = [1, 2, 3];
$scope.ys = [{"name": "one", "the-number": 1},
             {"name": "une", "the-number": 1},
             {"name": "two", "the-number": 2},
             {"name": "deux", "the-number": 2}, 
             {"name": "three2", "the-number": 3},
             {"name": "trois1", "the-number": 3}];
```

I want to iterate over `xs` and then filter `ys` by the bound `x` in the iteration. Can I do this entirely in my template? Something like this?

```
<div ng-repeat="x in xs">
  <h1>{{x}}</h1>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="y in ys|filter:{y['the-number']:x}">{{y.name}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The compiler is saying that the `[` is unexpected, but it's the only way I know how to reference field names that aren't JavaScript ident characters.

Here's the (broken) code in plunkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/tjKzQxLu9zWTzlPtogAG

Comment: Can you create a plunker? Here is a blank template http://plnkr.co/edit/GGU2QRS5kzxIMk0UcPFX?p=info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://plnkr.co/edit/d3EOFx4XD8tK3WiOZBmq?p=preview

This worked for me:

```
  <div ng-repeat="x in xs">
    <h1>{{x}}</h1>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="y in ys| filter: {'the-number': x}">{{y.name}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: This doesn't specify the field though does it?

Comment: No it does not, sorry, the example was simple.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, that matters. I've updated my example to illustrate how it could fail.

Comment: Magic (as in 'excellent' and 'grr angularjs magic')! Thanks for your efforts.